# Consulta Ajax não funciona

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Bom, uma simples consulta ajax, php e mysql.
Este mesmo código alterado apenas pelo nome do campo funciona normalmente em outra página.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#email').keyup(function(){ 
var Email = $(this).val(); 
var EmailResult = $('#div_mensagem_valida_email'); 
if(Email.length > 3) { 
EmailResult.html('Verificando..'); 
var UrlToPass = 'action=email='+Email;
$.ajax({
type : 'POST',
data : UrlToPass,
url  : 'include/cadastra_novo_cliente_verifica.php',
success: function(responseText){ 
if(responseText == 1){
EmailResult.html('<span class="error">Ops, este e-mail já está cadastrado</span>');
}
else(responseText == 0){
EmailResult.html('');
}               
}
});
}else{
EmailResult.html('Aguardando...');
}
if(Email.length == 0) {
EmailResult.html('');
}
});

$('#email').keydown(function(e) { 
if (e.which == 32) {
return false;
}
});
});
```

O input é:

```
<input id="email" class="form-control input-lg" type="text" name="email" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Seu e-mail" required>
```

Simplesmente não acontece nada, no Firebug não me retorna erro

Comment: Mas na aba Rede (network) mostra a requisição pra página `include/cadastra_novo_cliente_verifica.php`? Na aba console mostra algum erro de sintaxe do front-end (javascript)?

Comment: `var UrlToPass = 'action=email='+Email`. Que isso ? Action = Email = Email

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, não mostra, no console me aparece apenas 'SyntaxError: missing ; before statement'

Comment: Esse é o seu problema `SyntaxError: missing ; before statement'` há um erro de sintaxe no seu javascript que irá afetar o funcionamento e nada irá executar, **lembre-se** erros de sintaxe impedem do resto do script que veem depois funcionar... Essa mensagem de erro fala que faltou um `;` em algum lugar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aqui você esqueceu do `elseif`, veja:

```
}
else(responseText == 0){
```

O correto é:

```
}
else if(responseText == 0){
```

Recomendo fazer uma boa indentação do código também, deve ficar algo como:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#email').keyup(function() {
        var Email = $(this).val();
        var EmailResult = $('#div_mensagem_valida_email');
        if (Email.length > 3) {
            EmailResult.html('Verificando..');
            var UrlToPass = 'action=email=' + Email;
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                data: UrlToPass,
                url: 'include/cadastra_novo_cliente_verifica.php',
                success: function(responseText) {
                    if (responseText == 1) {
                        EmailResult.html('<span class="error">Ops, este e-mail já está cadastrado</span>');
                    } else if(responseText == 0) {
                        EmailResult.html('');
                    }
                }
            });
        } else {
            EmailResult.html('Aguardando...');
        }
        if (Email.length == 0) {
            EmailResult.html('');
        }
    });

    $('#email').keydown(function(e) {
        if (e.which == 32) {
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Ferramentas como SublimeText ou ferramentas online como http://jsbeautifier.org devem lhe ajudar.